# Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I've added the android-support-v7-appcompat,android-support-v7-mediarouter library project to build path.

following are my main activity and no errors for import the button, but when execute the app, error inflating MediaRouteButton happens.
Thanks a lot for any advice!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
> 
<android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
            android:id="@+id/castbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            >
</android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton>'
```

...

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity 
        implements OnClickListener {
private android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton castbutton;
```

Comment: Correct this first `android.support.v7.app.`MediaRouteButton`` with `android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton` remove single quote from 'android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should replace this

```
<android.support.v7.app.`MediaRouteButton`
        android:id="@+id/castbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        >
</android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton>
```

With

```
<android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
        android:id="@+id/castbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        >
</android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton>
```

**Update:** You must `appcompat referecning` first. To add appcompat library into your Follow the steps `Right Click Project--> go to properties--> android ---> ib tab` to add the appcompat project.

Comment: Sorry, that's the writing mistake when edit the question. In fact the MediaRouteButton didn't such error. Ecllipse will detect such error and provide suggestions. There's not build error/problems in my project.

Comment: @cc5zhenhua have you referenced appcompat properly?

Comment: Yes. I've tried to add item to java build path, android project preference but not working. Still wandering anywhere missed in my project.

Comment: Finally get the solution. It's really my appcompat issue. SHould be Project--properties--android---lib tab to add the appcompat project.
At first I just add them in the build path.

Comment: @cc5zhenhua then if its an appcompat referecning  issue the solution posted does not solve the problem. You should unaccept this answer