# MediaRouteButton - XML binary #34 exception

Tags: android, chromecast

I was com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' for my project and was able to get the mediaRouteButton to showup and work just fine. I recently updated all my libraries to 23.3.0 and now whenever I start the application it will crash with this exception:

```
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
   at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:19792)
```

I have looked at the other questions/answers regarding this error however the solutions did not work and I noticed that the other questions regarding this show the same inflateException but on line #74 not #34. Does anyone have any idea why this worked on previous library versions and how to fix this? Is this a bug with the new libraries?  This is different from the other questions since I have tried their accepted answers and the line # that the error is occuring on is not the same.

Comment: have you added   compile "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:21.0.3"

Comment: Yes, so the version I have is 23.3.0 which gradle tells me is the newest version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965402/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-app-mediaroutebutton)

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the original question, I understand that the question has been asked however the other questions including that link have proven unhelpful. Most reference #74 not line #34,